# Question about existence of function with given derivatives

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f_n : U \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a given sequence of functions of class $C^\infty$ on open subsets $U \subset \mathbb R^n$. Does there exist a function $F:\mathbb R \times U \rightarrow \mathbb R$  of class $C^\infty$ such that 
$$
\frac{\partial^n f}{\partial t^n}(0, x)=f_n(x) 
$$
for  $n=0,1,2,\ldots $ and all $x \in U ?$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma

Comment: This looks to me like a parametrised version of Borel's theorem.  Am I interpreting it correctly?

Comment: Thanks for help. I did not know earlier that it is Borel's lemma.

Answer (score 1):

This is Theorem 1.2.6 in L. Hormander, Analysis of linear partial differential operators, vol. I.

Comment: Yes, but in Hormander books is assumed additionally that each $f_n$ has compact support.

Comment: This is not important. Using the standard technique, partition of unity, (Hormander, section I.1.4) one gets rid of the assumption
of compact support.